# Ordering rows respecting groups using Datatables jquery plugin

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, datatables

I have been taking a look at [Datatables documentation](http://jquery-datatables-row-grouping.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/customGroupOrdering.html) about grouping but I think that's not what I am looking for.

[image]

I have a table with two groups of colums. Half left and half right. 
The rows at the left are related to the ones at the right so that one row in the left can be related to many rows at the right.

I won't use any sorting options for the half right side of the table but I would like to add this options for the ones in the left side.

The thing is that the number of rows in the left side still being the same as the rows in the right but some of them are empty. (`<td></td>`) in order to show the relation between the rows at the left side and the ones at the right side.

Now, using the default sorting of Datatables plugin if i order by a column of the left side, it will take into consideration the empty rows and will order them also plus i will lose the relation between the left side and the right one of the table.

Is there any possible solution to solve this using any of the Datatables options?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I solved it.

At first i took at look at the [Grouping Add-on](http://jquery-datatables-row-grouping.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/index.html) of DataTables but it didn't work well with sorting and filtering so I decided to do it in another way.

Every row would have data. In case it is a group, then it will be duplicated BUT it would be hidden with a concrete CSS style.

Like this, the user would see "groups" and the filtering and sorting will work as always.

In case of a search filtering, using jQuery, I show again the first row of each group (in case the search return a hidden half row)